# Java making a semi-random array out of a random number

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I've been struggling to get this working. I want to add 1 and 2 to a number that was randomly generated from 1-7 and store it in an array for example: If the random number generator got 3, I want the array to store 3, 4, and 5. Here is my code:

```
    byte[] locationGen = new byte[1];
    for(byte i = 0; i < locationGen.length; i++) {
        locationGen[i] = (byte)(Math.random()*7+1);
    }
    byte[] locations = new byte[3];
    locations = (locationGen, locationGen+1, LocationGen+2);
```

Everything works as intended except for the locations variable and I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Have you tried `= (locationGen[0], locationGen[0]+1, locationGen[0]+2);` ?

Comment: That returned "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: byte cannot be converted to byte[]" when I tried to compile it.

Comment: You don't have to *run* code to see compilation errors in Eclipse. Those red squiggles should tip you off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have true motivation to use the `byte` type, and using `byte` makes Java code unnecessarily complex. I suggest the following solution:

```
int[] locations = new int[3];
for (int locationGen = (int)(Math.random()*7) + 1, i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
  locations[i] = locationGen + i;
```

If at some point you really do need the `byte`, then convert to it at the last moment.

Comment: Why are you trying to write obfuscated code? Just put the int locationGen business on it's own line for heaven's sake.

Comment: I will if you can explain to me *why* this is obfuscated code. `locationGen` is only used within the loop and I have made its scope appropriate to that fact. You want me to export the variable to the surrounding scope and force the reader to check to make sure that it is only used within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize arrays with `{}`, not `()`, in Java.

Your initial loop makes no sense, as your array has only one location in it. You could do this:

```
byte locationGen = (byte)(Math.random()*7+1);
byte[] locations = {locationGen, (byte)(locationGen+1), (byte)(locationGen+2)};
```

Things to note there:

1. In both cases I left the `3` off the declaration. It's unnecessary, and if you change the initialization, it becomes a maintenance issue.
2. I fixed the typo on the third entry (you had `LocationGen` with a capital `L` — Java is case sensitive).
3. Because the result of adding an `int` (`1` or `2`) to a `byte` is an `int`, you need to cast back.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, unless you have a valid reason to create a single position byte array to store your random `locationGen` byte:

```
byte locationGen = (byte) (Math.random()*7+1);

byte[] locations = new byte[]{locationGen,  (byte) (locationGen+1), 
(byte)(locationGen+2)};
```

In the solution you posted, you were getting an error because you weren't  accessing the locationGen array position (locationGen[0]) before making the sum, that's probably why you were having the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
byte locationGen = (byte)(Math.random()*7+1);
byte[] locations = {locationGen[0], (byte)(locationGen[0]+1), (byte)(locationGen[0]+2)};
System.out.println(locations[0] + ":" + locations[1] + ":" +locations[2]);
```

Your loop didn't make much sense, so I dropped it. Arrayinits are done with "{" and "}" and not "(" and ")". Last but not least, there were a few indices missing when you tried to init the array "locations".

Comment: Please add some comments to your answer, what was wrong and how it should be fixed

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you're coming to Java from something else like Python. In Java the parenthesis `()` are only used for order of operations, not lists, tuples or anything else. Furthermore, the comma operator in general expressions is a "return last thing in the list" type of operator. It's best to explain with an example:

```
int i = 1,2,3,4; // same as int i = (1,2,3,4);
System.out.println(i); // prints 4
```

So your code needs to be something along the lines of (not sure if Java has changed recently to allow assigning arrays like such):

```
byte[] locationGen = new byte[1];
for(byte i = 0; i < locationGen.length; i++) {
    locationGen[i] = (byte)(Math.random()*7+1);
}
byte[] locations = {locationGen[0], locationGen[0]+1, LocationGen[0]+2};
```

Also, if you wanted to merge three arrays, you'll have to do that with another loop like such:

```
byte[] locationGen = new byte[1];
for(byte i = 0; i < locationGen.length; i++) {
    locationGen[i] = (byte)(Math.random()*7+1);
}
byte[] locations = new byte[locationGen.length*3];
for(int i = 0; i < locationGen.length; ++i) {
    locations[i] = locationGen[i];
    locations[i+locationGen.length] = locationGen[i] + 1;
    locations[i+2*locationGen.length] = locationGen[i] + 2;
}
```

Also, as a small comment on your code, I don't see a good reason to use a byte as the counter in the for loop. All Java arrays are indexed by `int`s and using a byte likely won't save you anything. Stack variables (locals) tend to take up at least an `int`s worth of space anyway so you're not saving space, and operating on it as a strict byte likely wastes processor time. Just use an `int`.

Comment: I tried switching everything to int and using your code on the top (with the typo fixed) and it returned "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression"

Comment: You can't *assign* to an array variable using the array initializer. You can only *initialize* the variable at its declaration site. So your `locations =  { ... }` doesn't compile.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Right, that's why I mentioned that I wasn't sure. Somebody was using that syntax. Anyway, the bottom code should certainly work.

Comment: You are also using a `for`-loop to iterate over an array with fixed size 1. What purpose does that serve in your code? Why are you even using an array of fixed size 1? Why wasn't that replaced with a simple variable? This is quite bad code, even more so with regard to its teaching value.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I did because the poster did. It is both arrogant and bad form to unnecessarily change the poster's code. In this case, I'm assuming that he wants to create several random numbers and then do this for each random number. That the "byte [] locationGen = new byte[1];" line is just to show us what locationGen is (to create a short example), but that an array will be passed in, or a length will be passed in or something along those lines.